# Namespace problems in QuickFix's .Net DLL wrapper

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, quickfix

I'm battling with the QuickFix engine in .Net (using the C++ DLL wrapper) to craft a `TradeCaptureReportRequest` message:

```
var req = new QuickFix44.TradeCaptureReportRequest();
req.set(new QuickFix.SubscriptionRequestType(QuickFix.SubscriptionRequestType.SNAPSHOT_PLUS_UPDATES)); // 263
req.set(new QuickFix.TradeRequestID("testing" + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString())); // 568
var nodates = new QuickFix44.TradeCaptureReportRequest.NoDates();
nodates.set(new QuickFix.TradeDate("20130201"));
req.set(nodates); // 580
```

Everything seems to look good until I call `req.set(nodates)`, which causes a compiler error saying that *"NoDates cannot be converted to a NoDates"*.

This boggles my mind since when I navigate to the metadata of the TradeCaptureRequest within the QuickFix dll, i am shown this.

```
public void set(NoDates value);
 // as a member of QuickFix44.TradeCaptureReportRequest
```

if I go to the definition of NoDates it sends me to the `QuickFix44.TradeCaptureReportRequest.NoDates` Class defined within the `QuickFix44.TradeCaptureReportRequest` class.

however there is a `NoDates` Class defined within the `QuickFix` namesapace which compiles just fine when I do the following.

```
req.set(new QuickFix.NoDates(1));
```

I'm using Quickfix v4.0.30128 and the .Net wrapper for the C++ DLL.

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is.  Are getting an exception, compiler error, etc.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the C# code for [`TradeCaptureReportRequest.set`](http://quickfix.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/quickfix/trunk/quickfix/src/.NET/fix44/TradeCaptureReportRequest.cs?revision=2291&view=markup) you'll find that it would like a `QuickFix.NoDates` type for the `NoDates` value:

```
// line: 1993
public void set(QuickFix.NoDates value)
{ setField(value); }
```

So change your C# to the following:

```
var nodates = new QuickFix.NoDates();
nodates.set(new QuickFix.TradeDate("20130201"));
req.set(nodates);
```

<sub>It appears you're using the QuickFix .Net wrapper over the C++, which is an abomination of .Net programming guidelines. I highly recommend you switch to [QuickFIX/N](http://www.quickfixn.org/tutorial/compatibility), which is less horrible (but still awful looking).</sub>

Comment: apparently i can do something like this, go figure... QuickFix44.TradeCaptureReportRequest.NoDates nodates = new QuickFix44.TradeCaptureReportRequest.NoDates();
                    nodates.set(new QuickFix.TradeDate("20130211"));
                    req.addGroup(nodates); // 75